# Как в БД засунуть массив байтов в ячейку типа blob?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

Этот код я использую для редактирования данных в БД. Когда данные типа int или string все работает, но я не могу понять как мне вставить массив байтов в ячейку с типом данных BLOB.
3 дня уже штурмую гугл, яндекс, youtube, но не могу найти решение.

```
OdbcTransaction transaction = null;
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand();

transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

command.Connection = connection;
command.Transaction = transaction;


command.CommandText = "UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file=" + bytes + " WHERE te_comp LIKE '" + ParStr + "'";
//command = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file=" + bytes + " WHERE te_comp LIKE '" + ParStr + "'", connection);
//command.Parameters.Add("@byte", OdbcType.Blob).Value = bytes;


command.ExecuteReader();
transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: Что за БД хотя бы?

Comment: База данных Transbase

Answer (score 3):

Никогда не используйте конкатенацию строк для составления sql-запросов. Это грозит [SQL-инъекцией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).
Всегда используйте параметризованные запросы: [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter), [3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection).

Вы не указали, какую именно СУБД и провайдер используете. Можно ли применить именованные параметры или только позиционные.

Массиву байтов в .NET соответствует тип `OdbcType.Binary`. См. [Specifying parameter data types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#specifying-parameter-data-types). И лучше смотреть именно английскую версию документации, потому что перевод на русский очень плох.

Ну и наконец не забываем освобождать занятые ресурсы.

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
using (var command = new OdbcCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    command.CommandText =
        "UPDATE tb_vs SET te_file = ? WHERE te_comp LIKE ?";

    command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Binary).Value = bytes;
    command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = ParStr;

    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш код, теперь буду знать как указывать параметры. Но при попытке его использовать получаю ошибку: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: "ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC TransBase Driver][TransBase]General error.
TransBase Exec error report:
type of parameter 0 does not match (got binchar(*), wanted blob). Хотя при работе с типом int код работает.

Answer (score 1):

Решил.
Заменил OdbcType на Image:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Image).Value = bytes;
```

Хоть там файл и не Image, но видимо все равно какой формат файла так как это просто байты.

Alexander Petrov спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вероятно, это специфика вашей СУБД Transbase. Или провайдера.